# Type hints and autocomplete for dict entries in Python

Tags: python, autocomplete, static-analysis, type-hinting

I have the following batch definition

```py
batch = {
            'id': ids,
            'input': [texts, text_lens],
            'target': {
                'dp' : {
                    'heads': heads_target,
                    'deprels': deprels_target
                },
                'fgpos' : target
            },
            'mask': mask,
            'pred_mask' : pred_mask
        }
```

Is it possible to create a dict in Python and expose the fields so that in my IDE i can see type hints and autocomplete?

For example, ideally I would like to be able to write:

```py
batch.
```

and get the following autocomplete options: `id`, `input`, `target`, `mask`, `pred_mask` with any type hints they might have. Also i would ideally want to access a field like so:

```py
batch.target
```

and if i write

```py
batch.target.
```

i would also get autocomplete and type hints for `heads` and `deprels`.

Note that these batches are never modified. I hypothesize that when writing the batch definition, a Python class must be created and the proper fields must be set in order to be visible to static analysis.

**Is what I'm describing possible and a good practice?**

Comment: Not really possible. Definitely not good practice. Have a look at json schema...

Comment: Have a look at PEP589 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/

Comment: TypedDict seems to be a good alternative to what I want. By writing a little more extra code to annotate the type of the batch I can get completion suggestions for the keys. Do you mind answering the question? it seems a pretty good alternative

Answer (score 0):

Recently [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html) started supported adding type-hints from IDE with suggestions. Even with the support, I doubt you will able to achieve auto-completion for the dictionary variable.

The issue with the dictionary is the `keys` and `values` can be any type even if you annotate `dict[str, Union[int, str, float]` and the [typeddict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) can only achieve type-annotation not the auto-complete part.

To achieve the same functionality with the `.` dot-notation, you consider using [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). Then the IDE and type-hints will work as expected.

Here is an example code using python 3.9 with typing. If you're using 3.8 or less you can use `typing.List` to achieve the same behavior.

```
 from dataclasses import dataclass
  
  @dataclass
  class Position:
      x1: int
      y1: int
      x2: int
      y2: int
  
  @dataclass
  class Target:
        fgpos: Position
  
  @dataclass
  class DPTarget:
        heads: list[Position]
        deprels: list[Position]
  
  Mask = Position
 
 @dataclass
 class Batch:
        id: list[int]
    input: list[str]
    target: Target
    mask: Mask
    pred_mask: Mask
```